# Dynamic loading of javascript causes target to iframe corruption

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, target

I am rendering a page which dynamically creates an iframe as part of the page. Content renders in the iframe when it is created. I also have a link which "targets" the iframe for rendering additional pages.

The code that renders inside the iframe dynamically loads javascript. However, when you click the link which targets the iframe name, instead of the content rendering in the iframe, a new window is created as though target="blank". If I comment out the dynamic loading of the javascript the link target= works fine every time.

As far as I can tell I am doing the dynamic loading properly. The js code loads and executes properly. However, I'm not sure what is happening to the DOM to foul up the target. Any help would be appreciated.

page1.html:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var ifr = "<iframe width='998' name='main'
         id='main' src='page2.html' scrolling='no'
         frameborder='1'  height='100'></iframe>";
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#content").html(ifr);  
          $('iframe').load(function() {
             this.style.height = 
              this.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 60 + 'px';
          });
      });
    </script>
   <body>
    <div id="wrapper" style="height: 100px;">
      <p><a href="index1_mgc1.html" target="main">Click Me</a></p>
      <div id="content">
      </div>
    </div>
   </body>
```

page2.html:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
  // var ScriptLoaded = true; 
  if (typeof ScriptLoaded == 'undefined') {
      var scripts = ["js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"];
      for (i=0; i<scripts.length; i++) {
        var name = scripts[i];
        loadScript(name, function() {
        });
      }
   };

   window.onload = waitForLoad();

   function loadScript(name,callback) {
       var script = document.createElement('script');
       script.type = "text/javascript";
       if (script.readyState) {  // IE
          script.onreadystatechange = function () {
             if (script.readyState == "loaded" ||
                  script.readyState == "completed") {
                script.onreadystatechange = null;
                callback();
             }
          }
       } else {      // Other
         script.onload = function() {
           callback();
         }
       }
       script.src = scripts[i];
       document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
  };
  function waitForLoad() {
    if (typeof jQuery == "undefined") {
       setTimeout(waitForLoad,500);
    }
  };
</script>
<body>
<div class="page">
  this is in an iframe
</div>
```

Comment: What makes it fail for me when I copy & paste your code is that in JS, you can't declare Strings on multiple lines like this. Try declaring `var ifr` in one line, or using concatenation.

Comment: Thank you blex for spotting that. I did change that declaration to just 1 full statement.

Answer (score 0):

I've looked for a *natural* solution, but there does not seem to be one.

`target="someIframe"` does not like it when the iframe is dynamically created. Here is a workaround you could place after creating the iframe:

```
$('a[target="main"]').click(function(ev){
    var src = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#main').attr('src', src);
    ev.preventDefault();
});
```

It will select every link that has the iframe as a target, and when you click on them, it will get their `href`, set it as the iframe's `src`, and prevent the link from opening in a new window.

Comment: Thank you Blex. That worked like a champ. God bless!